# GeoTIFF RGB as leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, rgb, geotiff

I'd like to put a GeoTIFF RGB as a Leaflet overlay.
I can read the GeoTIFF file in javascript but end up with 4 arrays (R,G,B,alpha) and don't know how to create an image out of these arrays.

To elaborate in more detail:
I use [Pytroll](http://pytroll.github.io/index.html) to create a Seviri "natural" composite and save it as GeoTIFF (the image looks similar to the last one from this notebook: [Example image](https://github.com/pytroll/pytroll-examples/blob/master/satpy/hrit_msg_tutorial.ipynb)

Then I use the Leaflet Plugin [Leaflet.CanvasLayer](https://github.com/IHCantabria/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field) to load the GeoTIFF, following this [example](https://ihcantabria.github.io/Leaflet.CanvasLayer.Field/example_ScalarField_Geotiff.html). (Note that they use a single band in their example, not an RGB with multiple bands)

Doing so, I get 4 arrays (R,G,B,alpha). Now, I have the problem of "stitching" these channels together to arrive at a single image. Maybe this is very obvious, but I don't see the solution.

I also tried to use [geotiff.js](https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js) and load the GeoTIFF directly from there with the readRGB function, which yields a large Uint8Array, but then I don't know how to put this on Leaflet.

Any hints or ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?